# Why is my domain account's registry hive being unloaded?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, windows-registry

I have a domain consisting of two ASP.NET web servers (load balanced) and a SSRS server. We set up the domain to allow the web servers to access the SSRS web service, and the SSRS is also the domain controller. There is also a windows service on each application server. The domain has an account set up which is responsible for the web application pool on each web server, and also runs the windows service and the SSRS service. Periodically we are experiencing an issue on a web server where the web application is failing to write a file to the local disk. Restarting the application pool fixes the issue. Upon inspection of the app pool process using Process Monitor, we can see that while it is trying to write the file, it is encountering a "HIVE UNLOADED" message while trying to query the domain account's registry hive. We can also see frequent Windows Event 16 occurring on both application servers and the SSRS / Domain Controller server, which states that a registry hive's access history is being cleared.

My question: is there anything I can do to stop the domain account's registry hive being cleared? Also, in order to help with our investigations, is there a safe way to trigger the hive being cleared in order to reliably reproduce the issue?

Comment: Does the event 16 show up if you stop the application pool and the site in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Event 16 is expected as it shows the result of RegIdleBackup scheduled task.

As for the main problem,you can set Idle time-out to 0 for your application pool, to prevent it from shutting itself down. This will show you if the problem is related to this or not.

Also, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971248/how-to-diagnose-app-pool-issues) link. Someone says that isolating application pools and adding more RAM resolved their issue.